# How can i get my sale price to have a different color then my regular price?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

He everyone,
I was wondering how I can get the sale price to have a different color than the regular color. And have the regular price a stripe through it. Here is the link for the site: http://www.peachandhoney.nl/product/classic-chair/ but I also want it to show up in the product gallery list http://www.peachandhoney.nl/shop/. If had tried editing this with this code but it is not working it changes both the prices. Any advice on how I can achieve this?

```
    .product .summary .price .amount {
    color: #e78484 !important; }
}
```

Comment: Is there any difference class name?

Comment: try adding a different class . It would be helpful if you post the code through snippet

Answer (score 4):

Target the `<ins>` tag in your CSS

```
.product .summary .price ins .amount {
    color: #e78484 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Only problem is that this does not show up on the peachandhoney.nl/shop or homepage where the product has preview display. How can i get that to work?

Comment: In this case I would recommend adding a class to the sale price, then target the new class to globally change it's CSS

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work with using

```
    .product .summary .price del .amount {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: line-through
    }

    .price ins .woocommerce-Price-amount {
    color: #d98159 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add other classes that change color:

```
.sale {
     color: green;
}

.regular {
     color: black;
}
```

then change the classes by `JS`;

Answer (score 0):

please consider to not use `!important` in your CSS.
It's bad practice.

It would be better if you could change the template as you like.

Anyway, it should work with:

```
    .product .price .amount {
            color: #e78484 !important;  
    }
    .product .price .amount ~ .amount {
            color: #111 !important; 
            text-decoration: line-through
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Only problem is that this does not show up on the http://www.peachandhoney.nl/shop/ or homepage where the product has preview display. How can i get that to work?

Comment: @QuintyvanDijk you do not have the `.summary` container there. i adjusted my answer. which should now work for both situations

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using only CSS like this example:

```
.sale .price ins {
    color: #ea1000 !important;
}
```